# android softkeyboard sample code does not change keyboard

Tags: android

I loaded the android Sample code for Softkeyboard onto my Nexus.  It shows me the option of picking the Soft KeyBoard Service under settings->language->keyboard.  I select the new service and also a language, but when i go to the web browser and focus on the url field I get the same system keyboard popping up, nothing different.  Has anyone tried the sample project and got a different looking keyboard?  Is there something I'm missing when running the apk?

Comment: Assuming you have done everything properly, does the sample code provide any Log output?

Comment: I've just installed this on a Fire HD and I can confirm I'm having trouble too. I check the custom keyboard in the settings as you mention, and it isn't available when I go to enter text. When I go back into the settings after leaving, the custom input method is unchecked again. It's as if the setting to use it will not save. Sorry I can't be more help. Good luck.

Comment: @AC it only prints load done.  it looks successful

Comment: @dokkaebi..thanks for checking. i tried Fire HD and after i check it, it gets removed.  on the nexus i tried and check stays but i don't see anything different.  i'm wondering what is the best way to debug this.

Comment: Are you sure the web browser you are using does not select the keyboard programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked available input methods? Just touch and hold on any text field (<4.0) or open notification bar and choose input method while keyboard is opened.

Comment: i'm using 4.0   and found when the keyboard is up u can go to notification bar or hold down on the settings button inside the keyboard.